# Ionic: Redirect Android app after keycloak login

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, keycloak, android-deep-link

I have an ionic 6 app (using capacitor 3) and i am using Keycloak as authentication provider. My current keycloak version is V 14.0.0.
When i test the web  version of the web all is working fine, but when i move to Android i can`t redirect to the app when the user make the keycloak login.

This is my KeyCloak client config:
[keycloakconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLYtq.png)

I have already set up the deep links in android manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http://bec02:8080/auth/" android:host="com.test.kctestapp"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

But once authenticated the page cant be found:

[pagenotfounderror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5CrX.png)

What can i be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: We've got the exactly the same problem here. Not able to find a solution since weeks.
As soon as we find solution, we let you know

Answer (score -1):

Try using following redirectUrl in your case both in Keycloak config and Application redirectUrl parameter:

```
com.test.kctestapp://
```

Comment: this is not even a valid redirectUri for Keycloak config